# Use cmd.exe to add registry key for current user failed

Tags: c#, cmd, registry, registrykey

I am creating a installer file by using Visual Studio Installer Project. During the installation, user will select target directory and installing for All users or Current user. After user make the selections, I will use these info to add a registry key at local machine(all users) or current user, depends on user's selection. It worked for local machine but not for current user. I wrote custom action code and the method will be called in commit method.

Following is the code to add registry key:

```
    public void CreateReg(string cmd, bool allUsers)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + cmd;

    if (allUsers)  // If create key for all users.
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    process.Start();
}
```

If it's for current user, allusers = false. I've logged string cmd, if I enter the cmd in an command prompt, a current user registry key will be created. It also works if I created a separate project only adding registry key. Just not work in the custom action. Did I miss something? Thanks!

Comment: Which kind of custom action it is? Deferred or immediate? Anyway adding a registry value by a custom action is a bad idea.

Comment: @montonero It's immediate. And It's in the Commit method. Can you explain why it's a bad idea to add registry in custom action? Thank.

Comment: Because in this way you'll need to write the similar actions for an uninstall and a rollback sequences. And you're not guaranteed against any errors in your script or any issues in an environment due to which your script will not work as expected. In your case it should be much simpler to do this by means of MSI (although I'm not familiar with what VS Installer Project can do in this regard).
Have you checked the log of installation? What it says about this custom action?

Comment: It's usually a bad idea because there's lots of functionality *built into* MSI for manipulating the registry. Why is your registry key/value so special that it can't be done using the more normal means?

Comment: @montonero @ Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the response! The registry I want to add is for a chrome extension, not for the application. The chrome extension  will look through the registry to locate the application was installed. So, uninstall the application and rollback is not a concern.